# Regex for selecting hostname from CSS font-face rules

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to build a regex in Ruby that selects the hostname from CSS files (in order to perform a replacement with `gsub`) but am struggling to construct one that works for this use case.

There are other URLs in the file (some are in the comments, and some are to include other CSS files within it), so it can't be overly greedy.

I'd like to select *only* the scheme and the hostnames in the `src` `urls` of the `@font-face` rules, not URLs that are present in the comments or otherwise in the file. (i.e., I want `//fonts.example.com/` to be selected from the example below)

Example data that the regex will be run on:

```css
*/\n/* A commented out url about copyright https://example.com/copyright */\n/*
 */\n/*{\"last_published\":\"2017-09-19 09:55:28 UTC\"}*/\n\n@import url(\"https://example.com/additional.css");\n\n@font-face {\nfont-family:\"neuefranklink\";\nsrc:url(\"//fonts.example.com/k/neuefranklin.woff2\") format(\"woff2\"),url(\"//fonts.example.com/k/neuefranklin.woff\") format(\"woff\"),url(\"//fonts.example.com/k/neuefranklin.otf\") format(\"opentype\");\nfont-style:normal;font-weight:900;\n}
```

I've gotten as far as this regex: `/(?<=url\(\"\/\/)/`, but it breaks past the first backslash in the scheme. If you have any solutions for this, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answer

### Brief

Unfortunately, there's no direct way to do this with regex. What you can do, however, is use a workaround to determine where each `@font-face` is located and then find any urls within them.

---

### Code

**Step 1:** Get each `@font-face` content into capture group 1

```
@font-face\s*{([\s\S]*?)}
```

**Step 2:** Find urls within the content of capture group 1 from **Step 1**

```
url\("(.*?)"\)
```

---

### Results

#### Step 1

**Input**

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"neuefranklink";
    src:url("//fonts.example.com/k/neuefranklin.woff2") format("woff2"),url("//fonts.example.com/k/neuefranklin.woff") format("woff"),url("//fonts.example.com/k/neuefranklin.otf") format("opentype");
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:900;
}
```

**Output** - Capture group 1

```
font-family:"neuefranklink";
src:url("//fonts.example.com/k/neuefranklin.woff2") format("woff2"),url("//fonts.example.com/k/neuefranklin.woff") format("woff"),url("//fonts.example.com/k/neuefranklin.otf") format("opentype");
font-style:normal;
font-weight:900;
```

#### Step 2

**Input** = `Step 1` **Output**

**Output** - Capture group 1

```
//fonts.example.com/k/neuefranklin.woff2
//fonts.example.com/k/neuefranklin.woff
//fonts.example.com/k/neuefranklin.otf
```

---

## Edits

### Edit 1

The code below has been provided by [zetacu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2580302/zetacu) (see comments under this answer for original post).

```
string.gsub(/@font-face\s*{([\s\S]*?)}/){
    $1.gsub(/url\("(.*?)"\)/){
        "<<#{$1}>>"
    }
}
```

### Edit 2

There is a possibility for using a single regular expression, although, I wouldn't necessarily suggest it. There are a few things that could break this regex, then again, the same thing would break the current regex (such as `content: "}"`), but, depending on its usage, it may work.

**Note**: This regex uses PCRE regex flavour and so may not work in most regular expression engines. You can test it on [regex101](https://regex101.com)

```
(?:@font-face\s*{|\G(?!\A))[^}]*?url\("(.*?)"\)(?=[^{]*?})\K
```

This is a lot more complicated to explain, so I'll let regex101 do most of the explanation (copy/paste it into the `REGULAR EXPRESSION` input box and hover the tokens). If someone does want clarification on some of the tokens used or the way they are used, however, I'll be more than happy to explain them.

Comment: I agree this code will replace the url with whatever you need `string.gsub(/@font-face\s*{([\s\S]*?)}/){ $1.gsub(/url\("(.*?)"\)/){ "<<#{$1}>>" } }`

Comment: @zetacu Thank you! I've added your code to my answer under the **Edit** section (with proper citation).

Comment: @ctwheels and @zetacu, thanks for the help with this! There is one portion I am still struggling with - how to make the output of the final capture group only `//fonts.example.com/`, without the rest of the font URL? I am looking to only replace the `scheme` (i.e., `//`), and an `hostname`, (i.e. - `fonts.example.com`) to create a relative URL - not the entirety new URL. So the final output of the `src` portion should resemble `url("./k/neuefranklin.woff2") format("woff2"),url("./k/neuefranklin.woff") format("woff"),url("./k/neuefranklin.otf") format("opentype");`

Comment: Use `url\("(\/\/)([^\/]*?(?=\/|")).*?"\)`, the first capture group is the scheme, the second is the domain

Comment: It's close - but it's losing the important part of the font url. I want to keep the `/k/neuefranklin.woff2` portions and replace the `scheme` and `hostname` only.

Comment: @codeadventurer then use `(url\(")\/\/[^\/]*?(?=\/|")(.*?"\))` and replace with `$1something.com$2` where `something.com` is obviously the replacement string

Comment: @ctwheels this worked for me in conjunction with your original answer. Thank you so much for your help with this!

Comment: You're very welcome @codeadventurer. There is another option, but I don't think it'll work in ruby, I could, however, be wrong. I've edited my answer to include it.